# I would've been late not if my mom woke me up on time

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have this sentence:

> I would've been late not if my mom woke me up on time

Does this sentence make sense? if not, how should I correct it? And how should I correctly use "not if"?  Could anyone share with me some helpful sentences?

Comment: Hello Ezekiel, how do you think the sentence should be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **would’ve been** late if my mom **hadn't woken** me up on time.

The sentence above is correct. It's a third conditional. We use third conditionals talking about unreal situations in the past. *"In fact, I wasn't late because my mom had woken me up. But I would have been late if she hadn't woken me up."* You can read more about conditionals [here](https://enguroo.com/2018/06/08/conditionals/).

Since you are asking for sentences with "not if," here are a few:

> We'll be late! - **Not if** we leave right now. (= We won't if we leave right now.)
>
> The new product will be a failure. - Well, **not if** it's good. (= It won't if it's good.)

As you can see, "not if" is often used when someone is replying to something someone else has said. It's to emphasize that something will not happen under some condition.

Comment: are you saying "would've" is wrong or just expanding to the complete phrase? as I say would've all the time

Comment: @WendyG I just expanded. There’s nothing wrong with “would’ve”. I should probably edit the answer not to confuse anyone. Thank you for your comment.